# Using a string as stdin in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I know that we can use a file as stdin like

program << file.txt

but is it possible to use a string as stdin ?

Comment: Are you accidentally answering your own question here? That's awesome.

Comment: Ha, I didn't notice that before I posted my answer

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill No I was not knowing that :) . I tried like 
program >> my stinrg but that was not working

Comment: The example in your question is invalid.  file.txt is not used as input in that case but as the string marking the end of a here doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use syntax called a *here document:*

```
program << EOF
input
more input
even more input
EOF
```

This is supported in several UNIX shells, as well as in some scripting languages like Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
echo "My string" | program
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` supports "here strings" with the following syntax:

```
program <<<"your input goes here"
```

This will be treated approximately the same as

```
echo "your input goes here" > tmp
program < tmp
```